# Xamarin Forms ListView onpressing event

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to change the Image by changing the IconToShow propery with binding (programmatically), when the item is pressing.

How can I trigger an OnPressed event ??

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuList}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding MenuStyle, Converter={StaticResource not}" SeparatorColor="Blue">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding IconToShow}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: by Onpressing you mean tab and keep the finger in the cell? or OnClick? only tap and remove the finger?

Comment: I mean tab and keep the finger in the cell @MarioGalván

Answer (score 0):

So for LongPress events inside a cell you will need a custom renderer of a cell to do what you need, here are some links that may help you:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58487/listview-long-press-tap-delete-popup

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18798/detect-long-tap-on-listview-item

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27323/how-can-i-recognize-long-press-gesture-in-xamarin-forms

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be nice if you could include code instead of links. Thank you!