# long press event on listview items in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to implemnet long press event on listview item and need to open a custom popup with listview item details. I tried long press with Behaviour on Listview, But in this case I am not able to get the item on which user is implementing the long press. I guess because I am calling it from listview not from the listview cell. So I tried to implement it  with listview cells also, but in that case long press command is not executing. If I do it on any control outside the listview, then this long press command exuctes but from listview cell it is not executing the long press command.

Is there any way to excute long press command from listview cells?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304300/xamarin-forms-listview-onpressing-event similar question/helpful answer

Comment: Hi ,could you share the code of long press event of `ListView` ? I will check that where problem is .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I was doing it with help of effects, but it was not working within listview. Outside ListView this was working fine. Now I am doing it with help of custom renderer of Grid which I am using in Listview and its working fine.

Comment: @anand Okey , glad you have solved that ! You can update this in answer , then other people will know that :-)

Comment: Hi , remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the url which helped me to accomplish my task. I referred this url and created custom renderer for Stacklayout which I am using in viewcell and implemented the long press event as mentioned here.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/longpress-event-for-image/

Hope it will help others also.